# Can I always use "unless" interchangeably with "if not"?

Tags: meaning, differences, conditionals

I have been bothered by the question whether 'unless' and 'if not' can be used interchangeably. I think they can have the opposite meaning, but I am not sure. Could you support my opinion with some examples or theory?

I was also presented with a sentence:

> Unless I had lost the umbrella, I would have go out now.

But I know *unless* is used to refer to the future, anyway, might it be correct?

Comment: That is one strange sentence. Usually "unless" is paired with a negative, as in "Unless you do as I say, you won't get to go to the circus." Even in cases where it is paired with a positive, the subordinate clause speaks of a deficit: "Unless I'm wrong, you're going to go to the circus." "Unless we fail in our task, we will all be rich."

Comment: RE: That is one strange sentence - I wonder if maybe the O.P. is trying to say, "Unless I've lost my umbrella, I'm going out [into the rain] now." That might make more sense.

Comment: Yes, it does, but if it were the sentence you mention I wouldn't have asked the question :)

Comment: Who presented that sentence to you, then?

Comment: *If* and *unless* have opposite meanings, but *if not* and *unless* have identical meanings.

Comment: I think this is Not Constructive. Offhand I can't think of *any* well-formed sentence where you can directly replace *unless* with *if not*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think you are misunderstanding then.  That is not the point.  We are not talking about textual substitution.  We are talking about sense.

Comment: @tchrist: I'm talking about the *question title*. You're obviously talking about something else.

Comment: @tchrist except as Peter Shor shows, in the sentence OP provided, the senses are not interchangeable. "Unless I had lost the umbrella, I would" is ungrammatical; "If I had not lost the umbrella, I would..." is fine. So there must be a difference.

Comment: Okay, I've thought of a "close, but no cigar" pair. *You may not enter this club **if not** wearing a tie* seems just about acceptable, as does *You may not enter this club **unless** wearing a tie*.

Answer (score 2):

You yourself have presented an example where they cannot be used interchangeably.

The sentence:

> If I had not lost the umbrella, I would have gone out,

is good English. The sentence:

> *Unless I had lost the umbrella, I would have gone out,

sounds very strange to a native English speaker. The reason is that you can only use "unless" in the past if the verb is habitual. For example:

> The pizza never arrived hot unless I tipped the delivery boy,

sounds fine.

Put those two sentences into the future, and they both sound fine:

> If I do not lose the umbrella, I will go out,
>   Unless I lose the umbrella, I will go out.

Comment: Thanks for spelling this out like that; it was a real eye-opener. Your starred sentence can only be grammatical if it is habitual, and I have no idea why.  The OED sheds no light on the matter, defining *unless* as *except* or *if..not*. It does include some older citations that are hard to make sense of from a contemporary point of view, such as this one: 1710 Swift *Jrnl. to Stella* 8 Oct., ― I was at a loss to-day for a dinner, unless I would have gone a great way.

Answer (score 0):

Got your point. That said, a minor tweek to the conditional statements will make the phrases interchangeable:

Examples:

If your answer is not received by 8 tonight, we will not go to school tomorrow.

Unless your answer is received by 8 tonight, we will not go to school tomorrow.

Comment: you can [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/94034/edit) you original answer to include this extra detail.

Comment: And can you back up Robusto or can it be always used not matter if the sentence is positive or negative or a person wants to use unless referring to the past?

Answer (score -1):

"Unless" and "if not" are not interchangeable. They are two different beasts but I will try to clarify their usage and leave the final answer to you!!!

Unless starts a conditional statement.

Example: you refuse to do something unless something else happens.

"If not" is used to interject or clarify something or when the possibility of a better or different situation is possible.

Examples:
Investing in the business will yield 10% more, if not, you get your money back.
Let's meet today if not, tomorrow!

Comment: You need to be careful with punctuation here. "Let's meet in Rome: if not, in Paris" means "Let's try to meet in Rome, and if that doesn't work let's meet in Paris"; "Let's meet in Rome, if not in Paris" means "Let's try to meet in Paris, and if that doesn't work let's meet in Rome."

Comment: Thanks but I meant 'If not' as the one used in the conditionals, as Unless it rains, we will go and if it doesn't rain we will go. I wrote 'if not' because of different auxuliary verbs we can have in conditionals. I do know what you are saying, but can you relate?